# How to delete specific child from matplotlib seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn jointplot to create a contour plot and respective distributions. [image]

As the **pearsonr** is not relevant for the message of the figure and I wanted to remove it (to avoid confusion). I was neither able to block it being put there when launching the seaborn jointplot command, neither did I find a way so far to remove the child from the plot.

```
ax.get_children()
```

command returns the following children:

```
[<matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x7f03778cdc90>,
 <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x7f03778e5b90>,
 <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x7f0377703dd0>,
 <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f037ba60c90>,
 <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f0378325310>,
 <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f0377754a10>,
 <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f0377754f50>,
 <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f037776e4d0>,
 <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f037776ea10>,
 <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f037776ee90>,
 <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f03776f73d0>,
 <matplotlib.quiver.Quiver at 0x7f0377b79dd0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f037789a6d0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f037789a710>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f037789a750>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x7f037789a790>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7f03778cdb50>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7f0377953f50>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7f03778cd9d0>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7f03778bb390>]
```

But ax.get_children()[12].remove() finishes with

```
raise NotImplementedError('cannot remove artist')
```

It also seems that seaborn somehow blocks plt.ion() or/and other redraw stuff.
I am expecting the solution to be quite simple (some combination of find_object command + delete). Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn.jointplot):

> **stat_func** : callable or None
>
> Function used to calculate a statistic about the relationship and annotate the plot. Should map x and y either to a single value or to a
>   (value, p) tuple. *Set to None if you don’t want to annotate the plot*.

So when calling `jointplot`, just set `stat_func` to `None`.